# Need to create a RedHen Contact for each Drupal User

Tags: users

I'm wanting to upgrade a current site to use the RedHen CRM module to track contact engagement (etc.) but first need to create RedHen contacts (redhen_contact module) for each of the users.  I'm familiar with Drush scripts so would be fine writing up a script but I'm unfamiliar with the internals of how RedHen works in Drupal.  Is there anybody who knows it already who might be able to help point the way?

**Note**: This is not a third-party api. It's a CRM built within Drupal as a Drupal module. What I'm asking is the proper form to utilize the Entity API to create contacts within the RedHen CRM module programmatically.

Comment: How many users? Might be able to do it with Batch API.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This site is just for questions about Drupal, questions about unrelated 3rd party APIs will need to be asked somewhere else

Comment: @Clive: It's not a third-party api.  It's a CRM built within Drupal as a Drupal module.  What I'm asking is the proper form to utilize the Entity API to create contacts within the RedHen CRM module programmatically.  Does that make sense?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this... bottom line is you could use Rules and trigger on user create or user update and fire a custom action, or create a module and do it on entity insert/update of type user. Then employ the RedHen Contact API, view its source for an example.

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you for your input.  RedHen does automatically create and synchronize contacts when users are created and data is updated.  Hmm... perhaps that's a method I could use to 'auto-generate' the contacts without needing to set all of the contact entities' fields myself.  Will explore.

Answer (score 1):

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) might be the quickest way to achieve this.

You could have one that on user create, generate a new contact for that user, and a separate rule that after a user updates their information update their contact.

[image]

According to RedHen documentation, they have direct rules support so this seems like an easy addition.